# jQuery Load Using Bootstrap Less

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Evening guys!

I asked a question a couple of days ago and couldn't get the solution: whenever I was using jQuery's .load() call to grab another .HTML page in my directory, why is a lot the content came out weird and not formatted right, but something like buttons from Bootstrap were correctly being shown?

Well I did some more digging I found what is exactly happening, but doesn't know why or what. When using jQuery `load()` like this:

```
$("#mainmenu").load("ready.html");
```

to get another HTML page to load into a div called `mainmenu`, I found some content get altered by `grid-framework.less:18` :

```
.row {
    /* margin-right: -15px; */
    /* margin-left: -15px; */
}
```

Along with some h1/h2 tags get messed up by **type.less** from Bootstrap with others. These LESS calls were all overriding my CSS file and regular plain old Bootstrap, when in the div before the `load()` call nothing happens.

As of right now I'm using Bootstrap's CDN to reference the framework. To fix it, do I have to download Bootstrap and just find these LESS files and delete this? And more importantly, why are these LESS files overriding everything?

Answer (score 0):

**I have external file name ready.html from which i m reading data and loading in to my id="mainmenu"**
 ***To make this code run, just add html page name ready.html in your project and add full content from :*** https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_theme_company_complete_animation

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Theme Made By www.w3schools.com - No Copyright -->
    <title>Bootstrap Theme Simply Me</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#get').on('click', function () {
                $('#mainmenu').load('ready.html');
            });
        });
    </script>


    <style>
        body {
            font: 20px Montserrat, sans-serif;
            line-height: 1.8;
            color: #f5f6f7;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        .margin {
            margin-bottom: 45px;
        }

        .bg-1 {
            background-color: #1abc9c; /* Green */
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        .bg-2 {
            background-color: #474e5d; /* Dark Blue */
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        .bg-3 {
            background-color: #ffffff; /* White */
            color: #555555;
        }

        .bg-4 {
            background-color: #2f2f2f; /* Black Gray */
            color: #fff;
        }

        .container-fluid {
            padding-top: 70px;
            padding-bottom: 70px;
        }

        .navbar {
            padding-top: 15px;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
            border: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            font-size: 12px;
            letter-spacing: 5px;
        }

        .navbar-nav li a:hover {
            color: #1abc9c !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="mainmenu">
    <button type="button" style="color:black" id="get">show ready.html</button>
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Me</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">WHO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">WHAT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">WHERE</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- First Container -->
        <div class="container-fluid bg-1 text-center">
            <h3 class="margin">Who Am I?</h3>
            <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle margin" style="display:inline" alt="Bird" width="350" height="350">
            <h3>I'm an adventurer</h3>
        </div>

        <!-- Second Container -->
        <div class="container-fluid bg-2 text-center">
            <h3 class="margin">What Am I?</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Third Container (Grid) -->
        <div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
            <h3 class="margin">Where To Find Me?</h3><br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    <img src="birds1.jpg" class="img-responsive margin" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    <img src="birds2.jpg" class="img-responsive margin" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    <img src="birds3.jpg" class="img-responsive margin" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer class="container-fluid bg-4 text-center">
            <p>Bootstrap Theme Made By <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">www.w3schools.com</a></p>
        </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to download less version of Bootstrap to edit small part of code. You can use simple css to modify such things without worrying about anything else. I suggest using initial property in yours case instead. That will bring back margin values for row to default.

Just simply add:

```
.row {
    margin-right: initial;
    margin-left: initial; 
}
```

in a css file or `<style>` tag, that will be loaded AFTER bootstrap.

Read more about initial property here [enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp).

Comment: Whoops I should have known I guess... haha... But do you know why JQuery's .load() function takes from .less files from Bootstrap?

Comment: jQuery CAN'T take less from bootstrap. LESS needs to be compiled to CSS before it can be parsed by a browser... At least not if you don''t have a browser side less compiler. If you had one you probably would know about it, right? Maybe you have some *.map files (or something like that) which point in browser to less files instead of css, as a code source in general... If so, deleting map files should cause browser to point at css files instead